# Hi Lo Card Game In Java

Tags: java, class, object, random

So I have to code a HiLo card game program in java and here are the instructions on how it works:

there are two classes Card and Deck

The Card Class contains 2 private variables int suit and int faceValue
A Constructor which takes the 2 variables as parameters like this:

- Card(int suit, int faceValue)
- Getters --> getSuit:int and getFaceValue:int
- A compareTo(Card card):int method
- A toString():String method

The Deck Class contains a private random variable of Random type 
private random : Random
A no parameter constructor Deck()
A deal method that takes no parameter and of Card type

The Card class has a suit which is a digit from 0 to 3 that represents the suit of a card:
-   0 represents Spades (which is the highest ranked suit)
-   1 represents Hearts (the second highest suit)
-   2 represents Diamonds (the third highest suit)
-   3 represents Clubs (the weakest suit)

The faceValue is a value between 1 and 13; 1 represents Ace, 11 is Jack, 12 is Queen and 13 is King.

The compareTo method compares the current instance (i.e., this) with the parameter card. If the two objects have the same suit and faceValue, the method returns 0. If the current instance is higher (higher value, or if they are the same value, higher suit), then the method returns a positive value (it can be +1 or any other positive value since the magnitude is not important, only the sign). If the current instance is lower, return a negative value.

The toString method returns a String representation of the card (e.g., “Ace of Spades”, “2 of Hearts”)

The Deck class has an instance of type Random which it uses when 
instantiating and dealing a new Card.

Now code an application class called HiLoApp which will:
-   instantiate a Deck object
-   deal and display the first card
-   ask the user to choose -1 if they think the next card will be lower, +1 if the next card will be higher, or 0 to quit the game
o   deal and display the next card
o   display whether the user chose correctly
o   count the number of attempts and correct guesses

The main method is to continuously carry out these steps until the user enters 0 to quit the game. At this point, display the total number of attempts and correct guesses made by the user.

**Card class:**

```
public class Card
{
    private int suit;
    private int faceValue;

    //Constructor 
    public Card(int suit, int faceValue)
    {
        this.suit = suits; 
        this.faceValue = faceValue;

        card = deal(); //???

    }
    public int getSuit()
    {   
        return suit;
    }
    public int getFaceValue()
    {
        return faceValue;
    }
    public int compareTo(Card card)
    {

    }
    public String toString 
    {
        String cardName = null;

        switch (faceValue)
        {
            case 2:
            cardName = "Two";
            break;

            case 3:
            cardName = "Three";
            break; 

            case 4:
            cardName = "Four";
            break;

            case 5:
            cardName = "Five";
            break;

            case 6:
            cardName = "Six";
            break;

            case 7:
            cardName = "Seven";
            break;

            case 8:
            cardName = "Eight";
            break;

            case 9:
            cardName = "Nine";
            break; 

            case 10: 
            cardName = "Ten";
            break;

            case 1: 
            cardName = "Ace";
            break; 

            case 11: 
            cardName = "Jack";
            break;

            case 12:
            cardName = "Queen";
            break; 

            case 13: 
            cardName = "King";
            break; 

        }
        switch (suit)
        { 

            case 0:
            cardName += "Of Spades";
            break; 

            case 1: 
            cardName += "Of Hearts";
            break; 

            case 2:
            cardName += "Of Diamonds";
            break;

            case 3:
            cardName += "Of Clubs";
            break; 
        }

        return cardName;
    }
}
```

**Deck Class:**

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Deck 
{
    private Random random;

    public Deck()
    {
        random = 0;
    }
    public Card deal()
    {
        while (num != 0)
        {
            random = new Random();

            suit = random.nextInt(3);
            faceValue = random.nextInt(13) + 1;

        }

        return //how to return suit and faceValue at the same time?

    }
}
```

**Application Class:**

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class HiLo
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        //to quit the game 
        int num;

        //getting input from user
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        Deck deck1 = new Deck();

        = deck1.deal()
    }
}
```

My questions are: I don't understand where the card parameter in the compareTo method comes from. Also the reason why I am not able to fully code the program is because I don't understand how it works exactly. Where does the initial dealing of the first card happen? Does the card class have access to the Deck class in order to use the deal method? I see the deal method returns a Card class type but how can I return both the suit and the faceValue at the same time?

Comment: You should be asking your teacher these questions.

Comment: I did but its online you see and I can't just wait around for her to reply. I am really trying to figure it out but everytime I think I got it I end up having more questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't understand where the card parameter in the compareTo method comes from.

It comes from a function call you will be writing.  Examples:

```
Card card1 = deck.deal();
Card card2 = deck.deal();

if (compare (card1, card2)) ...
```

The first deal comes in main where you say `deck1.deal()`.

The Card class doesn't need to use the deal method, but HiLo does, when it says `deck1.deal()`.

The way to return a suit and a faceValue at the same time is to return a Card:

```
public Card deal()
{
  ...

  Card result (suit, faceValue);
  return result;
}
```

That's really the *point* in having a class (a big point, anyway):  to bundle things together that go together.  A Card is a bundle of a suit and a faceValue.  Now that it exists, use it wherever you need, well, a Card.

Comment: does every deal use the deck1.deal() that i created in the HiLo app ?

Comment: Yes, that's how you should write it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have the responsibilities the wrong way around. A deck creates the cards, the card does not need to know about the deck at all. Think about it this way - a card can exist without a deck.

So in your deck constructor, you should probably make all the 52 cards, and keep them in a list. Then when you call `deal` on the deck, it removes the top card from the list, and gives it out as the return value.

As for the `compareTo` method - normally you implement the [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface. Then, if you have a list of cards, and want to sort it, the list will take the cards, two at a time, and compare them.

Comment: Although, I can't just create all the card possibilities because in this case it's not just 1 deck its unlimited number of decks together

Comment: Okay, that's reasonable. Either way, the deck is responsible for giving out a new card when you call `deal`. In your `main` method, you create a deck; now you have to call `deal` to get a card and `System.out.println` to display the card you got.

Comment: also the assignment that i am given gives me the UML diagrams for the 2 classes Card and Deck. Deck contains a instance of type Random like this: private Random random. It has a no-arg constructor Deck () and a deal method that have a return type Card

Comment: but don't I need to deal cards twice at the same time so each time i can compare both ?

Comment: Google a `while` loop. You need to have a variable for the previous card, and one for the next card. Then, while the user has not entered '0', update next and previous by dealing another card.